# Why is $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ not differentiable at $0 \in \mathbb R^2$ given limit as $t$ approaches $0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $$f(x_1, x_2) = \frac {x_1^3 -x_2^4} {x_1^2 + x_2^2}$$ if $(x_1,x_2) \neq (0,0)$ and $$f(x_1,x_2) = 0$$ if $(x_1,x_2) \neq (0,0)$.

I've proven that $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 t (f(th)-f(0)) = \frac {h_1^3} {h_1^2+h_2^2}$$

Now, I'm wondering why this allow me to conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at the point $0 \in \mathbb R^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x_1,0)=x_1$ and $f(0,x_2)=-x_2^2$. This implies
$$f_{.1}(0,0)=1,\quad f_{.2}(0,0)=0\ .$$
When $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ the linear approximation therefore would have to be
$$df(0,0).(x_1,x_2)=x_1\ .$$
We now have to check whether the error
$$g(x_1,x_2):=f(x_1,x_2)-df(0,0).(x_1,x_2)=-{x_1x_2^2+x_2^4\over x_1^2+x_2^2}$$
tends to $0$ in the required way. To this end we write $(x_1,x_2):=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$ and obtain
$${\tilde g(r,\phi)\over r}=-\bigl(\cos\phi\sin^2\phi+r\sin^4\phi\bigr)\ .$$
Here the right hand side does not converge to $0$ when $r\to0+$. Therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: "in the required way" could be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

The limit you have calculated is the directional derivative $D_hf(0)$. When a function is differentiable, its differential is $df(0):h\mapsto D_hf(0)$, and *it must be a linear form in $h=(h_1,h_2)$*. Your formula clearly is not (quotient, powers...), hence you have indeed proven the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that, 
$$
f(h_1,h_2)-f(0,0)=A(h_1,h_2)+o(|h_1|+|h_2|),
$$
where $A$ is a 2x2 matrix. In our case $A=0$ and $f(0,0)=0$. Hence it suffices to show that
$$
\lim_{(h_1,h_2)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(h_1,h_2)}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}=0.
$$

Comment: Since $f$ is real-valued $A$ is a $(1\times2)$-matrix.